# Windows VPN и доступ к файлам

Tags: windows, vpn

Здравствуйте!
Имеем простейшую офисную сеть, в которой один компьютер выделен под файловую помойку. Работает он на Windows 10 Pro, имеет расшаренные папки с индивидуальными правами и включенный "Общий доступ с парольной защитой".
Изнутри сети проблем с доступом нет, пользователи заходят на указанный сервер, вводят логин и пароль и т.д.
Однако попросили сделать доступным указанный серверок извне. 
Что сделано:
1. На указанном сервере создано входящее подключение со статическим пулом IP адресов 192.168.0.200-192.168.0.230
2. На роутере проброшен порт 1723
3. IP адрес статический. 
VPN подключается без проблем, однако, возникла проблема с доступом к расшаренным папкам.
Имеем следующую структуру папок на сервере:
D:\Work
D:\Work\Folder1
D:\Work\Folder2 и так далее.
Права на указанные папки установлены стандартными средствами. При подключении VPN и попытке зайти на \192.168.0.200 папку Work видно, а вот её содержание уже нет. При этом, если открыть папку Work для всех, то её содержимое доступно.
Есть ли способ решить указанную проблему? Спасибо заранее за любую помощь.

Comment: А `samba` разве не на `445`-м порту живёт?

Comment: @donRumata samba да, но смысл в том, что сначала устанавливается туннель до офисной сети, и уже внутри него мы обращаемся по smb к серверу.

Comment: Я в курсе как работает vpn. А ещё я в курсе, что там есть куча своих реализацийвсяких штук типа dhcp. После установки соединения - порт самбы виден как открытый?

Comment: @donRumata Да. Причем, повторюсь, что я даже могу зайти на сервер и вижу расшаренную папку, а вот её содержимое - не видно.

Comment: Решил проблему. Оказалось, что если обращаться к серверу по IP в Lan то всё заработает. @donRumata спасибо!

Comment: Ну тогда тебе надо прописать в пушах vpn ещё и отсылание dns-сервера, чтобы адреса резолвились корректно. Ну чтобы `/etc/resolv.conf` был как в локалке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Оказалось, что если обращаться к серверу по IP в Lan то всё заработает.